# SQL: How to sum numbers in a column into a new column, but showing the new result after each row's sum?

Tags: sql

I have this:

| CustomerNo | Date | Usage |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1003 | 2018-05-25 | 202 |
| 1003 | 2018-06-25 | 86 |
| 1003 | 2018-07-25 | 17 |
| 1005 | 2018-05-25 | 305 |
| 1005 | 2018-06-25 | 100 |
| 1005 | 2018-07-25 | 62 |

And I need this:

| CustomerNo | Date | Usage | Reading |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1003 | 2018-05-25 | 202 | 202 |
| 1003 | 2018-06-25 | 86 | 288 |
| 1003 | 2018-07-25 | 17 | 305 |
| 1005 | 2018-05-25 | 305 | 305 |
| 1005 | 2018-06-25 | 100 | 405 |
| 1005 | 2018-07-25 | 62 | 467 |

I'm trying to sum the Usage column based on grouping by CustomerNo, and it will add based on Date order, and show the new sum as it keep progressing.  This is just an example, I've got a ton of these customerno with different dates and Usage.

I tried using Row_number and join the table to itself on the CustomerNo and Row Number and increasing it by one but it only looks at two values instead of continuing the sum so I get something like this which isn't what I want:

| CustomerNo | Date | Usage | Reading |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1003 | 2018-05-25 | 202 | 202 |
| 1003 | 2018-06-25 | 86 | 288 |
| 1003 | 2018-07-25 | 17 | 103 |
| 1005 | 2018-05-25 | 305 | 305 |
| 1005 | 2018-06-25 | 100 | 405 |
| 1005 | 2018-07-25 | 62 | 162 |

Thank you

Comment: I'd personally use a scripting language to "construct" what you are trying to do here.  It would be 5-10 mins of code writing to get that structure from a loop. ..  It's going to programmatically make more sense to the human eye, and it'll help keep your sanity with trying to write such a complicated SQL statement. -- Again this is just my humble opinion.

Comment: Thank you, I will work on that.  I think I have a good starting point so this questions can be closed.

Comment: Running sums are easily accomplished with a window function:  `sum(usage) Over (Partition By CustomerNo Order By Date Rows Between Unbounded Preceding And Current Row)`.

Answer (score 0):

You shoul use sum(), not row_number():

```
CREATE TABLE mytable
(
    CustomerNo INTEGER,
    Date       TIMESTAMP,
    Usage      INTEGER
);

INSERT INTO mytable
    (CustomerNo, Date, Usage)
VALUES (1003, '2018-05-25', 202),
       (1003, '2018-06-25', 86),
       (1003, '2018-07-25', 17),
       (1005, '2018-05-25', 305),
       (1005, '2018-06-25', 100),
       (1005, '2018-07-25', 62);

select *, sum(Usage) over (partition by CustomerNo ORDER BY Date)
from mytable;
```

| customerno | date | usage | sum |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1003 | 2018-05-25 00:00:00 | 202 | 202 |
| 1003 | 2018-06-25 00:00:00 | 86 | 288 |
| 1003 | 2018-07-25 00:00:00 | 17 | 305 |
| 1005 | 2018-05-25 00:00:00 | 305 | 305 |
| 1005 | 2018-06-25 00:00:00 | 100 | 405 |
| 1005 | 2018-07-25 00:00:00 | 62 | 467 |

[DBFiddle demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/qMeeLPEB)

Comment: An alternative, using a subquery: [DBFIDDLE](https://dbfiddle.uk/PtKFqEBP)